# MongoDB - query for field inside array

Tags: mongodb

Here's a snapshot of my document:
[image]

I would like to know how can i retrieve only the documents where ANY of the `breakout` items has a property named `source`.

I tried the following: `db.getCollection('receipts').find({"sizeBreakout.packBreackout.breakout.source":{"$exists":true}})`
but a empty result is being returned always... why?!? what is the correct syntax for this query?!?
**Edit1:**
Attached File: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2zKseaQl2gnVlFWZFlaRzloMDg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please post your sample MongoDB documents.

Comment: Please post sample document here in your question. So that another person looking for similar issue, can take advantage of solution.

Comment: Also please let me know your MongoDB version? 3.2?

Comment: @Saleem mongo version is 2.6.11 & theres a link to the json in the question... its a large doc

Comment: Well, is it possible for you to upgrade mongo? I can write query for 2.6 but it will not be as efficient as for 3.2

Comment: @Saleem not my choice mate... i got stuck with it...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve only the queried element in an object array in MongoDB collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you have MongoDB 3.2, you can use this simple query.

> MongoDB version 3.2+

```
db.docs.find({$filter: {input: "$sizeBreakout.packBreackout.breakout", 
  as: breakout,
  cond:{$exists:{"$$breakout.source": true}}}})
```

> MongoDB version < 3.2

```
db.docs.aggregate([
{$unwind: "$sizeBreakout.packBreakout.breakout"},
{$match: {"sizeBreakout.packBreakout.breakout.source":{$exists: true}}}
])
```

This query will find all documents where `sizeBreakout.packBreackout.breakout.source` exists.

Comment: this script is supported only on MongoDB version 3.2+

Comment: checkout new solution and should work on MongoDB 2.6